# Celery chain not working with batches

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

At first glance I liked very much the "Batches" feature in Celery because I need to group an amount of IDs before calling an API (otherwise I may be kicked out).

Unfortunately, when testing a little bit, batch tasks don't seem to play well with the rest of the Canvas primitives, in this case, chains. For example:

```
@a.task(base=Batches, flush_every=10, flush_interval=5)
def get_price(requests):
    for request in requests:
        a.backend.mark_as_done(request.id, 42, request=request)
        print "filter_by_price " + str([r.args[0] for r in requests])

@a.task
def completed():
    print("complete")
```

So, with this simple workflow:

```
chain(get_price.s("ID_1"), completed.si()).delay()
```

I see this output:

```
[2015-07-11 16:16:20,348: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2015-07-11 16:16:20,376: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-07-11 16:16:21,406: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2015-07-11 16:16:21,449: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ultra ready.
[2015-07-11 16:16:34,093: WARNING/Worker-4] filter_by_price ['ID_1']
```

After 5 seconds, filter_by_price() gets triggered just like expected. The problem is that completed() never gets invoked.

Any ideas of what could be going on here? 
If not using batches, what could be a decent approach to solve this problem?

**PS:** I have set `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=0` like the docs say.

Comment: Just for the record, I needed so bad the batching thing that I ended up using RabbitMQ + Pika alone with a very simple worker template that buffers messages. If anyone interested, I have the source code available, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the behaviour of batch tasks is significantly different from normal tasks. Batch tasks are not even emitting signals like [task_success](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-success).

Since you need to call `completed` task after `get_price`, You can call it directly from `get_price` itself.

```
@a.task(base=Batches, flush_every=10, flush_interval=5)
def get_price(requests):
    for request in requests:
         # do something
    completed.delay()
```